# Como calcular a diferença entre duas horas distintas em milisegundos?

Tags: ruby

Qual a maneira maneira de calcular em milisegundos o tempo de uma ação no ruby?

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

`start_time = Time.now`

Executo determinado código que leva alguns milisegundos
`end_time = (Time.now - start_time)`

E como resultado obtenho por exemplo: 0.048813

A pergunta é: Este valor que eu obtive, está em milisegundos (ms) ou está em segundos?

Como eu faço para verificar ele com menos casas decimais, tipo 48.81 ms ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Segundo a documentação](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Time.html#method-i-2D), a substração entre dois tempos retorna um número de segundos. Sendo assim você pode obter o valor em milissegundos dessa forma:

```
delta_time = (Time.now - start_time) * 1000
```

Para exibir com apenas duas casas decimais você pode usar o *sprintf*. Dessa forma:

```
puts "%.2f" % delta_time
```

Comment: Perfeito.
Funcionou direitinho. Tinha visto a documentação mas não entendi essa forma de arredondamento.